# Is it possible to make CSS Pie timer run only once?

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-shapes

I use [CSS Pie Timer](https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/), and I struggle to make my pie loading animation run only once.

The order I want the animation to be in:

1. the circle is not shown
2. the circle is starting to fill up with a border color
3. the circle get filled fully
4. the circle **stays filled** (and doesn't repeat)

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pie spinner"></div>
  <div class="pie filler"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You just have to remove `animation-iteration-count`  - `infinite` and add `animation-fill-mode` as `forwards`.**

**Here is the working code**

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper, .wrapper * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.wrapper .pie {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #08C;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.wrapper .spinner {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%;
  z-index: 200;
  border-right: none;
  animation: rota 5s linear forwards;
}

.wrapper:hover .spinner,
.wrapper:hover .filler,
.wrapper:hover .mask {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.wrapper .filler {
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 0 50% 50% 0;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) forwards reverse;
  border-left: none;
}

.wrapper .mask {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 300;
  animation: opa 5s steps(1, end) forwards;
}

@keyframes rota {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes opa {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pie spinner"></div>
  <div class="pie filler"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514182/css-360-rotating-progress-radial-using-js/55515007#55515007 can you please solve this

Comment: @AnzilkhaN I will  post the answer