# Use inline style variable as SASS mixin include parameter

Tags: css, sass

With this HTML code:

```html
<div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress" style="--percent: 50; --color: red;"></div>
```

I wan't to use `var(--percent)` value as @mixin @include call in a scss file:

```css
@mixin draw-progress--solid($progress, $color) {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, $bg-color 50%, $color 50%);

    &:before {
        @if $progress <= 50 {
            background: $bg-color;
            transform: rotate((100 - (50 - $progress)) / 100 * 360deg * -1);
        } @else {
            background: $color;
            transform: rotate((100 - $progress) / 100 * 360deg);
        }
    }
}

.progress {
    @include draw-progress--solid(#{var(--percent)}, #8e44ad);
}
```

Tested and not working:

```css
@include draw-progress--solid(#{var(--percent)}, #8e44ad);
```

```css
@include draw-progress--solid(var(--percent), #8e44ad);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: you cannot because SASS is compiled first and then CSS variable are considered. You cannot use a CSS variable value inside a mixin SASS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Then I could do it without mixin/include, with all mixing code inside progress class.

Comment: Ok, no, because I can not use @if/@else conditional.

Comment: Having the `if else`, you cannot, you can only use something static

Comment: check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519869/8620333 .. I guess this is what you want to build

Comment: @TemaniAfif, oh! thanks! Please, add this comment as aswer to vote as valid!

Comment: if the other answer is exactly what you want, no need to repeat it. You can imply upvote it ;)