# CSS border time animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've an icon with a border on my login page:

```css
.border {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: var(--main-color);
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;
    border: 4px solid;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">✔</div>
```

I'm looking now for a way to add the border around with an growing animation because I've a timeout for login. The timeout is 60 seconds (60000 mil. sek.) so the border should be expanding from the right to the left all the round along. Is this possible?

**Update**

```css
.border {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'ETModules';
    font-size: 60px;
    color: var(--main-color);
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9998;
    background: #ffffff;
    --percentage: 100deg;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#ffffff)) content-box no-repeat, conic-gradient(black var(--percentage, 0), transparent var(--percentage, 0)) border-box;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) content-box no-repeat, conic-gradient(black var(--percentage, 0), transparent var(--percentage, 0)) border-box;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) content-box no-repeat, conic-gradient(black var(--percentage, 0), transparent var(--percentage, 0)) border-box;
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) content-box no-repeat, conic-gradient(black var(--percentage, 0), transparent var(--percentage, 0)) border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="border">✔</div>
```

I've used now the duplicate question / answer but the "border" is thicker then 5px. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you interested in svg with javascript solution?

Comment: When I can keep the HTML, why not

Comment: Temani can you please check this? It‘s really important because I need to deploy this tonight 

Comment: I've created something with svg and js, here is codepen https://codepen.io/nenadv91/pen/KONRQZ?editors=0010

Comment: @NenadVracar Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't change the HTML because this is a component of a framework :(

Comment: I already checked and I give you a duplicate question with at least 3 method to achieve what you want and you have considered the one with less support ...

Comment: Please check my updated question. The solution works but the width of the border is different... There is nothing about the width in your answer.

Comment: you didn't use *my* answer. In my answer the width of the border is controlled by border and in the code you used it's controled by padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've used your code now. But how can it let it go the other direction and how can I fill it with JS in 60 seconds? So like a timeout?

Comment: ifyou want something with JS consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519869/8620333 ... simply add a circle overlay above it to only show the borders

Comment: Hmm a bit choppy :/ can I make the animation smoother?

Comment: Found a really awesome way!